# Setting parent height according to child height

Tags: jquery, height

I have a slider with a few slides; every slide has a different height.

It works this way:

1st slide

```
<holder>
 <slide - display: block>
 <slide - display: none>
 <slide - display: none>
</holder>
```

2nd slide

```
<holder>
 <slide - display: none>
 <slide - display: block>
 <slide - display: none>
</holder>
```

etc.

slides have `position: absolute` (It has to be this way).

So the problem is: how to dynamically change height of `holder` to see whole content of every slide?

Now I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".holder").height( $(".slide").height() );
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".holder").height( $(".slide").height() );
  });
</script>
```

but it only uses the height of the first slide, so the other slides are cut off.

Please use javascript to help solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through them all to get the height of the tallest `.slide`.

```
function updateSlideHolderSize() {
    var max = 0;
    $(".slide").each(function () {
        max = Math.max(max, $(this).height());
    });
    $(".holder").height(max);
}
```

---

So it would go into your app like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(updateSlideHolderSize);
$(window).resize(updateSlideHolderSize);

function updateSlideHolderSize() {
    var max = 0;
    $(".slide").each(function () {
        max = Math.max(max, $(this).height());
    });
    $(".holder").height(max);
}
</script>
```

Comment: ok but how to paste it in this way :<script type="text/javascript"></script> and it has to change while window resizing (it's mobile site)

Comment: Ok works fine, 
how to add an option to add fex 10px to this height? and maybe you know how to change height according to actualy slide? I have slide with very different heights, fx 70px and 300px.

Comment: if you want to add `10px` to the height then do this: `$(".holder").height(max + 10);` If you want to set it to a particular slide's height then use `.eq()` to get the slide at that index. This will get the 2nd slide's height (index 1) `$(".slide").eq(1).height()`